# Is it possible to increase item size in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

After doing some research I found that the maximum size of an item (one row in a table) is 400 KB.

> *Source of research:* 
>  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items

I wanted to insert a text data that contains over 1 MB of size. This is basically one row worth of data.

**For example,**

I have a table called `users` which contains `summary` of the user.

The summary is a text field (String) and I want to insert data over 1 MB. But Dynamo DB allows only 400 KB.

**Note** 
I cannot store this in a file and keep a pointer

Comment: After doing some more investigation, I found that this is something I can do http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForItems.html#GuidelinesForItems.BreakingUpLargeAttribes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *not* store more than 400 KB worth of data in one DynamoDB item (or record).

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForItems.html#GuidelinesForItems.BreakingUpLargeAttribes) link, that you shared in your comment, requires you to break larger records into *multiple* items and handle merges in your application layer. This isn't supported transparently by DynamoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to note that a tactical way to store items larger than 400KB into DynamoDB tables is to use compression algorithms and save the compressed data as a binary attribute.

Clients need to compress and uncompress the data.

More information [here.1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html) and [here.2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIBinaryTypeExample.html)

Answer (score 0):

As the link mentions, you can break down the text summary into smaller chunks, let say of size w. Use indexes 1...n to store it. The value of n can be kept in another table.

What additional advantage this will give you is you can fetch the summary chunks parallelly.